# 2d Array contains other 2d Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

What can be the best solution for finding that a 2-D array contains any other 2-D array?
For example:

```
char a[][]={{'a','b'}, {'b','a'}}
char b[][]={{'a','b'}, {'b','a'}, {'a','b'}, {'a','b'}, {'a','b'}, {'b','a'}}
```

Then answer should be 2 because b contains a 2 times.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What should be the result of these arrays? `char a[][]={{'1','2'}, {'1','2'}}; char b[][]={{'1','2'}, {'1','2'}, {'1','2'}}`

Comment: Then answer should be 2.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I am not getting how to proceed. Any useful information will help.

Comment: @RajatSharma Are the dimensions of the two arrays fixed?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Is there any specific algorithm for this?

Comment: did the answer solve your question?

Comment: @Dante. No Dimension is not fixed. It may differ.

Comment: @RajatSharma Will Brute force method will do?

Comment: @RajatSharma Feel free for any queries.It will work for any dimensions now.

Comment: @Dante brute force will work but do you think it will work for input like this.(output should be 2 but as per your algo it is giving 4.)
  char a[][]={{'a','b'}, 
        {'b','a'}};
  char b[][]={{'a','b','c'}, 
     {'b','a','d'}, 
     {'a','b','a'}, 
     {'a','b','b'}, 
     {'a','b','a'}, 
     {'b','a','a'}};

Comment: @RajatSharma Definitely,it will.I have updated my answer.

Comment: @RajatSharma it works for all inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing a Brute Force solution here:

Idea:

Start at the top left corner(0,0) of matrix inside which you want to find another 2 d array.

Match the entries of bigger matrix with smaller matrix row by row and if all entries of all rows match,then the 2d array has been found. If any entry of any row does not match,then go for the next 2d subarray.

The next 2d subarray will start from (0,1).

We do this until no more subarrays are left to check for.

```
class Twodarray
{
 public static void main(String []args)
 {
  char a[][]={{'a','b'}, {'b','a'}};
  char b[][]={{'a','b','c'}, {'b','a','d'}, {'a','b','a'}, {'a','b','b'}, {'a','b','a'}, {'b','a','a'}};
  int c=number_of_2d_arrays(b,a);
  System.out.println(c);
 }
  public static int number_of_2d_arrays(char [][]arr1,char [][]arr2)
    {
     int i=0,j=0,c=0;
     while(true)
     {
      int row=i,col=j;      
      if(arr2.length>arr1.length-row)
      {
       break;
      }
      else if(arr2[0].length>arr1[0].length-col&&col==0)
      {break;}
      else if(arr2[0].length>arr1[0].length-col)
      {++i;j=0;}
      else
      {
       boolean matches=true;
       for(int a=0;a<arr2.length;++a)
       {col=j;
        for(int b=0;b<arr2[0].length;++b)
        {         
         if(arr1[row][col++]!=arr2[a][b])
         {matches=false;break;}
        }    

        if(!matches)
         break;
        ++row;
       }       
       if(matches)
        {++c;}
       ++j;
      }
     }
    return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. You are a life saver:)