# Java, Comparing a 2D Array to each iteration of another 2D array making an OCR

Tags: java

I am writing an optical character recognition project. I need to be able to search through a large array (can be any size really) of what is a field of nothing but ones and zeroes to find which 13x13 number template their layout most accurately reflects, in a very, very primitive OCR. It needs to move through each possible iteration of the larger array in a 13x13 block to see where it matches the digit array. It then gives a score where the better the match, the higher the score. My issue is that it just repeats the same 13x13 block without ever changing the iteration and moving to the side or down. The method needs to compare arrays of all the numbers (sample input array shown below) and say show which input array gets the highest score.

Here's my code:

```
public double compareMatrices(int[][] num,int[][] mat){
    double score=0;
    double highest=0;
    int n=0;
    for(;n+num.length<mat.length;n++){
        int[][] rows=new int[num.length][];
        int m=0;
        for(;m+num.length<mat[0].length;m++){
            for(int o=0;o<num.length;o++){
                rows[o]=Arrays.copyOfRange(mat[n+o],m,m+num.length);
            }
            int p=0;
            for(;p<rows.length;p++){
                int q=0;
                for(;q < rows[0].length;q++){
                    if((rows[p][q]==1)&&(num[p][q]==1)){
                        score+=1;
                    }
                    else if((num[p][q]==1)&&(rows[p][q]==0)){
                        score-=.25;
                    }
                    else if((num[p][q]==0)&&(rows[p][q]==0)){
                        score+=.25;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(score>highest){
            highest=score;
            score=0;
        }
        else{
            score=0;
        }

    }
    return(highest);
```

Here's a sample input array:

```
0000001000000
0000011000000
0000011000000
0000101000000
0000001000000
0000001000000
0000001000000
0000001000000
0000001000000
0000001000000
0000001000000
0000001000000
0000111110000
```

And I want to search through something like this

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: Maybe this answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32498856/2d-array-contains-other-2d-array/32518251#32518251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the updating of the score inside the innermost loop (of m, n):

```
for(n) {
  for(m) {
       int p=0;
        for(;p<rows.length;p++){
            int q=0;
            for(;q < rows[0].length;q++){
                if((rows[p][q]==1)&&(num[p][q]==1)){
                    score+=1;
                }
                else if((num[p][q]==1)&&(rows[p][q]==0)){
                    score-=.25;
                }
                else if((num[p][q]==0)&&(rows[p][q]==0)){
                    score+=.25;
                }
            }
        }
        if(score>highest){
          highest=score;
          score=0;
        }
        else{
          score=0;
        }
    } // end m
} // end n
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling that your problem is caused by the conditions of the for-loops. specifically at:

```
for(;n+num.length<mat.length;n++)
//AND
for(;m+num.length<mat[0].length;m++)
```

1- Why don't you just declare `n` and `m` inside the loop condition? Like this:

```
for(int n = 0; n+num.length<mat.length; n++)
for(int m = 0; m+num.length<mat[0].length; m++)
```

2- Why do you add `n` and `m` to `num.length`? Shouldn't it be something like this?

```
for(int n = 0; n<mat.length; n++)
for(int m = 0; m<mat[0].length; m++)
```

**Also,** note that in the nested loop you are NOT using `n` to to get the length of each "Horizontal Line" separately, but instead you are telling it to use the length of the first line always. `mat[0].length`

**My best guess with the information you have provided is that both loops might need some revision.**

Answer (score 0):

You've turned what should be a relatively simple quad nested loop into a bit of a monstrosity. You want to avoid creating new arrays, and just index back into the two that were passed in.

```
public double compareMatrices(int[][] num,int[][] mat){
  //TODO: I'm going to assume both arrays are rectangular and of at least length 1
  //     you should check this
  int nNumRows = num.length;
  int nNumCols = num[0].length;
  int nMatRows = mat.length;
  int nMarCols = mat[0].length;

  double highest=0;

  for(int row=0; row<nMatRows-nNumRows+1; ++row) {
     for(int col=0; col<nMatCols-nNumCols+1; ++col) {
       double score = 0;
       for(int row_offset=0; row_offset<nNumRows; ++row_offset; ) {
         for(int col_offset=0; col_offset<nNumCols; ++col_offset;) {
           int matRowIndex = row + row_offset;
           int matColIndex = col + col_offset;
           int numV = num[row_offset][col_offset];
           int matV = mat[matRowIndex][matColIndex];

           if((matV==1)&&(numV==1)){
             score+=1;
           } else if((numV==1)&&(matV==0)){
             score-=.25;
           } else if((numV==0)&&(matV==0)){
             score+=.25;
           }
        }
     }

     if(score>highest) {
       highest=score;
     }
   }
   return highest
 }
```